# Can I create/delete a cloudwatch event rule for an AWS lambda function from within that function?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function in aws that contains about 80 jobs- the jobs are triggered on a schedule by cloudwatch rules, and the lambda knows which job to run based on the parameters on those rules.

Some jobs require new cloudwatch rules to be created programatically, and others require old rules to be deleted.

Is there a way to create/delete the cloudwatch rules that trigger a lambda entirely from within that lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AWS Lambda function can call any AWS API.

To add a new Amazon CloudWatch Events rule, use:

- [`put_rule()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.put_rule) to define a rule, then
- [`put_targets()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.put_targets) to associate a target (eg an AWS Lambda function) with the rule

To delete a rule, use:

- [`remove_targets()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.remove_targets) and then
- [`delete_rule()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.delete_rule)